# Let $m$,$n \in N$ such that $m > n$ . Prove that $2(m-n)^2(m^2-n^2-1) \ge 2m^2 - 2mn + 1$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, contest-math

> Let $m$,$n \in N$ such that $m > n$ . Prove that $2(m-n)^2(m^2-n^2-1) \ge 2m^2 - 2mn + 1$

**my attempt ->**

$2(m-n)^2(m^2-n^2-1) \ge 2m^2 - 2mn + 1$

i.e., $2(m-n)^2(m^2-n^2+1) \ge 2m(m-n)+1$

i.e., $2(m-n)\{(m-n)(m^2-n^2+1)-m\} \ge 1$

i.e., $2(m-n)(m^3-mn^2-nm^2+n^3-n) \ge 1$

i.e., $2(m-n)\{(m+n)(m-n)^2 - n\} \ge 1$

*How to proceed from here ?*

Comment: As a policy, a question that is tagged "contest-math" should explain how it is related to a math contest. May I asked which contest contains this problem?

Comment: From an old IMO , I don't remember the year exactly 

Comment: It looks the $-1$ on the left-hand side should be $+1$, as Michael Rozenberg might have pointed out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inequality is wrong. Try $(m,n)=(2,1)$.

We obtain:
$$2(4-1-1)\geq8-4+1,$$
which is not so true.

The following is true.
$$2(m-n)^2(m^2-n^2-1)\geq2m^2-2mn.$$
Indeed, we need to prove that:
$$(m-n)(m^2-n^2-1)\geq m,$$ which is true because
$$(m-n)(m^2-n^2-1)\geq m^2-n^2-1=(m-n)(m+n)-1\geq m+n-1\geq m.$$

Answer (score 2):

> $2(m-n)\{(m+n)(m-n)^2 - n\} \ge 1$

You are also done!

- Recall that $m$ and $n$ are integers!
  The difference between two distinct integers is at least one.
  This is an immensely useful property of integers.
  Since $m>n$, $m-n\ge1$.
- Hence $(m-n)^2\ge1$ as well.
  $(m+n)(m-n)^2 - n\ge (m+n)-n=m\ge1$

Hence the product $(m-n)\{(m+n)(m-n)^2 - n\}\ge1$.